# What is the difference between setting proxy in package.json and webpack.config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, package.json

What is the difference between setting proxy in package.json and webpack.config?
How it is prioritised?
In my case  webpack does not pick proxy from package.json.

Comment: The `proxy` field in `package.json` is a Create React App feature. Are you using CRA?

Comment: No we are not using CRA